# no of solutions of the initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$x \dfrac{dy}{dx} = y , y (0) = 0, x \geq 0  .$

My Approach :

$\dfrac{dy}{y} = \dfrac{dx}{x},$ by variable separable method, we get

$lny = ln x +c $ and then raising e to both sides will get $ y=x+c.$  Then substituting the intial condtions, we get $c=-1$

so $y = x -1 $is the required solution.

But it's given that it has uncountable number of solution. I don't understand it.

Comment: You've not solved the differential equation correctly. You will get $\ln|y|=\ln|x|+C$ or $|y|=K|x|$ where $K=e^C$

Answer (score 2):

If you solve the differential equation correctly, then
$$\ln |y|= \ln x + c = \ln e^c x,$$
and so
$$y=\pm e^c x,$$
not $y=x+c$. Then $e^c \cdot 0 = 0$ for all constant $C$, given initial value doesn't give us a useful information.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\cdot\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}=y(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xy'(x)=y(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln|y(x)|=\ln|x|+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=e^{\ln|x|+\text{C}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\text{C}e^{\ln|x|}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\text{C}x$$

The given initial condition is not sufficient to solve for the
unknown constant, because:

If, $y(0)=0$:

$$0=\text{C}\cdot0\Longleftrightarrow \text{C}=\frac{0}{0}$$

And we can't divide by $0$.